# Set lists of images using bitmap class on Windows Phone

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, bitmap

i recently start developing windows phone apps ... well i tended to try using an image control to display a picture on it by setting the code below :

```
 Dim myimages As New BitmapImage(New Uri("/Add Radcontrols test;component/Images/screen.PNG", UriKind.Relative))
        Image1.Source = myimages
```

til now everything is perfectly working but .. i wondered if i could add more than one image and navigate between them by hitting a particular button existing in the UI of my windows phone emulator .

Comment: did you mean add more than one image?  "add more than image"

Comment: yes . yes more than one image .. thanks for the response .

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a List of image uri string. And upon a button clicked, create new `BitmapImage` using next image uri in the List, then set `image1's Source` to that newly created `BitmapImage`. That will be less memory-consuming then if you load all images at once and navigate between them. If those images are stored locally (not downloaded from internet) as what you seems to be doing currently, you'll see the effect as if all images loaded at once. No noticeable delay when loading next image, *that what I see so far in emulator*.

```
Dim imageUris As New List(Of String)
Dim nextImageIndex As Integer
...
...
'Upon button click
Dim myImage As New BitmapImage(New Uri(imageUris(nextImageIndex), UriKind.Relative))
Image1.Source = myimage
nextImageIndex += 1
'if index > last uri index, reset index
If nextImageIndex = imageUris.Count Then nextImageIndex = 0 End
```